# Regex to insert content just before mediawiki category links

Tags: regex, mediawiki, python-2.x

I'm trying to use a regex to insert a template into a page, before all category or interwiki links, but after everything else.
So if you have a page that ends like this:

```
== See Also ==
* [[Link one]]
* [[more link]]
* [//external.link external link]

[[Category:Pages]]
[[de:Spezial Page]]
```

I want the template `{{template}}` to be inserted before the `[[Category:Pages]]` but after everything else.

Note: The last section is not necessarily a list - it could be

```
== References ==
<references/>
```

or even something else. The point is to insert it before all category/interwiki links at the end, but after the last section.

What regex can help me do this? I've tried `(?P<pre>[\s\S]+)(?P<cats>(?:\[\[[^]]:[^]]\]\])*$)` as the matching expression with `\g<pre>{{template}}\n\g<cats>` as the substituting expression, but that simply inserts it at the very end.

Regex flavor: Python 2

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1394393 Use a real parser.

Comment: @jpmc26 any "real parser"s I can use to this end?

Comment: Dunno. I've never used Media Wiki. (But I do know when you're using a text processing engine that isn't really powerful enough for the language you're working with.) [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+mediawiki+parser) turns up a few results that look promising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, combining [jpmc26's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47234506/regex-to-insert-content-just-before-mediawiki-category-links?noredirect=1#comment81446598_47234506) and [mmm's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47237302/6605349), I figured it out:

```
import re
import mwparserfromhell as mw
#get content of page
wikicode = mw.parse(content)
links = wikicode.filter_wikilinks()
links = list(filter(lambda link: re.match(r'\[\[(Category:|[a-z][a-z]:).*\]\]', links))
wikicode.insert_before(links[0], '{{template}}')
content = str(wikicode)
```

Sorry for taking your time!

Comment: Note that many interwiki languages have three-letter codes, and some have fairly irregular names like `be-x-old` or `zh-min-nan` (see full list [here](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/source/mediawiki/browse/master/languages/data/Names.php)). Also if the wiki language is not English `Category` could be localized.

Comment: @Tgr I am aware of that, but in our case interwikis are only two-digit and the wiki language is English.

Answer (score 1):

From your example this `(==.+\s(?:[\*][\s].+\s)+)` for regex and `\1{{template}}\n` for the substituting expression will work just fine.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/BPBmFL

But maybe you have more cases that it won't work.

Edit:

Try this regex `((.|\n)*)(\[\[.*\:.*\]\]\n)` and this `\1{{template}}\n\n\3` substituting.

This way it will find everything until the category/interwiki links and you can insert the `{{template}}` after all and before the category.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/Bv14kt/4

Comment: Yeah, there's also cases like `==References==\n<references/>`, and not specifically See Also. Basically it needs to be inserted immediately after the last section, regardless of the content of the section, but _before_ the category/interwiki links.

Comment: That worked in your demo, but it inserts the template before the last _two_ category links - see [this](https://regex101.com/r/Bv14kt/5).

Answer (score 0):

Actually regexes *are* powerful enough for this specific task, although in general it is indeed a bad idea to use them for parsing wikitext. Something like

```
(\[\[(Category|\w{2,3}(-\w+){0,2}):[^\[\]<>]+\]\]\s*)*$
```

would work.

Comment: Hmm, very nice. However, I did figure out a solution using mwparserfromhell (which you have recommended to me in the past) (see my answer). I'll keep this in mind though, thank you!